# How to get the background color of a widget in GTK and Python?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I want to get the normal background color of a widget (a `GtkHeaderBar`, in this case). I'm currently using

```
style = self.get_titlebar().get_style_context()
```

to get the style, and

```
color = style.get_property("background-color", Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
```

to get the background color associated to that style.

However it returns a `Gkd.RGBA` object with the following properties:

```
Gdk.RGBA(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=0.000000)
```

But if I open GTK Inspector, select the HeaderBar, and goes to the style properties, it shows

```
background-color | rgb(57,63,63) | gtk-contained-dark.css:1568.29
```

What do I have to do to get these same values?

Edit:

I am experimenting with the `GtkStyleContext.render_background()`, but I'm having no success:

```
surfc = Cairo.ImageSurface (Cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 10, 10)
contx = Cairo.Context(surfc)
style = self.get_titlebar().get_style_context()
backg = Gtk.render_background(style, contx, 10, 10, 10, 10)
surfc.write_to_png("test.png")
```

The resulting file `test.png` is a `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` image.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at modifying the background-color with css. There is a very good [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkCssProvider.html) of it. It can be used with python with

```
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_path('application.css')
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
    css_provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
)
```

and a css file like:

```
GtkHeaderbar {
    background-color:@theme_bg_color;
}
```

**EDIT:** As you commented you do not want to modify the background color but retrieve the value of it. You can do `widget.get_style_context().get_background_color()` and it will return something like `Gdk.RGBA(red=0.913725, green=0.913725, blue=0.913725, alpha=1.000000)`.

However, you should note that `get_background_color()` is deprecated since there is not *one* background color. Some widget use a gradient as a background so it is not the best solution to use this method. See the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-get-background-color) for reference.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to modify the background-color with css. I wanna get the current background-color.

Comment: Yeap, I'm aware of `get_background_color()`. However it always returns `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Probably because the widget is using a gradient...

Comment: -1, this doesn't answer the question, and `get_background_color()` is deprecated as well as not supporting backgrounds other than plain colors, which is not, if not infrequently, the case. Most buttons, bars and even window backgrounds show gradient features nowadays.

Comment: How incredibly hard it was to stumble across this. Now I can finally paint my widgets in a different theme color. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, but there is an [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/issues/119) with new recommended way to get colors.

The [recommended workaround](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/issues/119#note_28626)
is to fall back to the deprecated `get_background_color()`

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

window = Gtk.Window()
context = window.get_style_context()
# this one is buggy
color1 = context.get_property("background-color", Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
print(color1)
# this is the deprecated version, but it is the recommended workaround
color2 = context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
print(color2)
```

From the [python/Gtk documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.get_property),

> Note that passing a state other than the current state of self is not recommended unless the style context has been saved with `Gtk.StyleContext.save()`

So the current recommended way to get a widget background color is

```
context = widget.get_style_context()
color = context.get_background_color(widget.get_state())
```

Often `self` is a Gtk widget, and this becomes

```
context = self.get_style_context()
color = context.get_background_color(self.get_state())
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested, I think the problem lies here:

```
backg = Gtk.render_background(style, contx, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

while it should be:

```
backg = Gtk.render_background(style, contx, 0, 0, 10, 10)
```

Comment: This was not the main issue (see my answer), but this is indeed why the `render_background` resulting image had zero size. Good catch !