# GTK: How to handle colors correctly

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I'm writing an application on GTK+3 with Python 2.7.

In a dialog of such application, the user is presented with two views of the same model. I want to highlight a row of the dialog when two of the columns are different. An example is clearer. The model looks like this.

```
ATTR | OBJ1 | OBJ2 | COLOR 
name | john | mike | red
```

I want the color to be 'red' as john and mike are different names. Then, on the tree view, I just set the background color of the cell to be 'red' if different, else 'white'.

Sounds simple, until I realized there is a infinite amount of themes out there. Even with the simplest dark theme around, this wouldn't work: the background color of the equal rows would be white, and that'd mean the user probably wouldn't even see the words (as he uses a dark theme, and the font color tends to be white on dark backgrounds).

How could I go about doing this?

Right now, I'm handling it like this, but I **know** it's wrong.

```
    # TODO: FIX THIS
    # this is the wrong way to do it, I'm creating a useless gtk.tree
    # so I can know the user's default color background
    # that not being bad enought, get_background_color is deprecated
    dumpy_tree = Gtk.TreeView()
    style = dumpy_tree.get_style_context()
    self.bg_color = style.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
    self.bg_color = self.bg_color.to_string()

    def decide_bg():
        """Decides which background should the row have depending on
        the uses default theme (light, dark, or unknown abomination)
        Pretty ugly, but it works"""
        color = self.bg_color.split("(")[1]
        color = color.split(",")
        color1 = int(color[0])
        color2 = int(color[1])
        color3 = int(color[2][:-1:])

        # that weird string formats from rgb to hexa
        default_bg = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (color1, color2, color3)

        if color1 > 200 and color2 > 200 and color3 > 200:
            return "pink" if first_prop != sec_prop else default_bg
        elif color1 < 100 and color2 < 100 and color3 < 100:
            return "darkred" if first_prop != sec_prop else default_bg
        else:
            # if your theme doesn't go for either dark or light
            # just use that color, screw highlights
            return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (color1, color2, color3)
```

Any info on how to better go about this?

Comment: You could (and probably should) set foreground color as well as background color.

Comment: That'd solve the problem of user not being able to even see the information, but is still inconsistent with the user's theme. Why should I have to force a white background? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You could set fg&bg colors on "red" cells and leave "white" ones as-is.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thinking too, and is actually what I am doing. The thing is getting the default background color is messy and deprecated,  at least the way I'm doing it.

Comment: `get_background_color` is [still the recommended workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813620/3565696) to get the background color. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39066419/3565696) should help a lot to handle colors in a cleaner way.